# Chess Game with Highest Scoring

Tags: chess

**Only one side has to have the score, the other can end with just a king for all I care.**

What game ends with the highest piece scoring? A trivial answer would be 38, using fools mate (or scholars mate)

But of course, pawn promotion can be a factor, so can you do better than 38? Is 102 possible? If so what moves does it require? If not, what is the highest piece scoring?

**PIECE SCORING:**

- **Pawn:** *1*
- **Bishop:** *3*
- **Knight:** *3*
- **Rook:** *5*
- **Queen:** *9*
- **King:** *0*

***BONUS: When giving the game, give the quickest version to achieve the high score!**

Comment: If one side plays to let the other win, then theoretically isn't it 103? 9 queens and 2 each bishop, knight, and rook?

Comment: @mdc32 What moves would you need to achieve that without losing any pieces or checkmating/stalemating your opponent in the process?

Comment: I think this question crosses the acceptable limit in Puzzling SE, you ask for moves and real game scenario

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Chess

Comment: @skv so does the question asking for shortest game with 18 queens. I consider this a puzzle.

Comment: @warspyking quoting another question is not a valid argument in my humble opinion...  one good test would be to post this question on Chess and see if they deem this a good fit... I am not saying it is required, but thats one option

Comment: @skv This is not about what is on topic on Chess imo.

Comment: I disagree with others saying that this isn't a puzzle. I think it's mostly like my successful [Generalized Path Guards puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5231/generalized-path-guards): it takes a familiar problem (playing chess) and then asks for a challenging proof of a generalized version of the problem. This isn't a chess question per say because it asks about chess, but instead it is a chess-themed puzzle that uses the rules of chess to convey a lot of complicated constraints quickly.

Comment: Another thought I had: knowing the answer to this question won't make you a better chess player because the situation is so arbitrary and far-removed from what you would actually find in a game, but it will make you better at solving other puzzles.

Comment: @Kevin. Agreed. So long as you know all the legal moves available in chess, you can solve the puzzle without ever having played/watched the game.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a solution that achieves the maximum possible 103 points (9 queens, 2 rooks, 2 bishops, 2 knights). It uses 40 moves, which is the minimum possible because a pawn must move 5 times in order to promote to a queen.

1. a4 e5 2. b4 d5 3. b5 c5 4. a5 f5 5. b6 g5 6. a6 h5 7. bxa7 Ke7 8. axb7 Kd6 9. c4 Ke6 10. d4 Kf6 11. dxc5 Kg6 12. cxd5 Kf6 13. d6 Ke6 14. c6 Kf6 15. d7 Ke6 16. c7 Kf6 17. e4 Kg6 18. f4 Kh6 19. fxe5 Kg6 20. exf5+ Kg7 21. f6+ Kg6 22. e6 Kf5 23. e7 Bg7 24. f7 Ke5 25. h4 Bf6 26. g4 Bg7 27. hxg5 Bf6 28. gxh5 Bg7 29. g6 Bf6 30. h6 Bg5 31. g7 Be3 32. h7 Kf4 33. bxa8=Q Kg3 34. axb8=Q Bf4 35. dxc8=Q Be5 36. cxd8=Q Bf4 37. e8=Q Be5 38. f8=Q Bf4 39. gxh8=Q Be5 40. hxg8=Q#

[image: Here is a gif of the game]